# User defined PostgreSQL function in hibernate dialect throws exception

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Is it possible to register a custom function written in database & written in extended hibernate Postgres Dialect as follows? Receiving function not exists exception on using this function in HQL.

Postgres function:

```sql
    create or replace function ADD_DAYS(varDate timestamp without time zone, varNumber numeric) 
     returns timestamp without time zone 
     LANGUAGE sql AS    
    $$ 
     SELECT (varDate + varNumber * INTERVAL '1 day')
    $$;
```

Java code:

```java
registerFunction("add_days", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "add_days(?1 , ?2)"));
```

Comment: Could you please provide hibernate config?

Comment: Any hibernate configuration is ok with this. Dialect need be custom dialect which extends Postgre specific dialect.
For the date fields TemporalType.TIMESTAMP & columnDefinition as date used.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask more specific question: what value do you use for the `hibernate.connection.url`? Do you use `hibernate.default_schema`?

Comment: Not using default schema. I'll try with solution you mentioned. Schema might come to rescue (Y)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced with the similar problem. The problem was in the following:

The function was created in the particular schema `TEST_SCHEMA`. When I used the following configuration:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">TEST_SCHEMA</property>
```

I got:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function levenshtein(character varying, character varying) does not exist. No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

But, when I specified the default schema explicitly in the connection url like below

```xml
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=TEST_SCHEMA</property>
```

my function became visible.